# why is changing the style in code with Delphi 10.2.3 incomplete? it worked ok with Berlin

Tags: ios, delphi, styles, firemonkey

using Delphi 10.2.3.Tokyo i opened the MobileControls sample that comes with Delphi and changed the target to iOS 64bit.
Then put 2 StyleBooks on it. Double clicked the first and loaded **iOSJet.style**. The Form gets dark. 
Then double click the second StyleBook and load **iOSSterling.style**.
Then i put a button on the form and on click event i typed:

```
if Form1.StyleBook = StyleBook1
   then Form1.StyleBook := StyleBook2
   else Form1.StyleBook := StyleBook1;
```

Finally i compiled and deployed the app to my iPad. The form shows dark (as it should). Clicking on the button changes the style, but not for all components - the background stayes dark.

I closed the app and ib the IDE changed the style of the form to StyleBook2 = the form changed completelly from dark to white (light gray), all components including the backgound.

Then i ran the app on my iPad and it showed all white.
Clicking on the button changed the style to dark, but again the background stayed white.

It appears that with Tokyo the backgground is not affected by a change of style - it stayes as it was with the style at start of the app.

I'm looking for a workaround as this was working perfectly with Delphi 10.1.2 Berlin.

Answer (score 0):

it is a bug in Tokyo - here's the link to Bug report and HowTo make it work:

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17771